# Using Popen with double qoutes and variables

Tags: python, variables, popen, double-quotes

I have spent hours working on this and reading through other questions on SO and the python docs, but haven't yet resolved this issue.

I am attempting to get python to send an echo command with double-quotes(") and correct spacing over ssh, using variables.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
ssh_upd = Popen([
    'ssh', server, 'sudo', '-S',
    "echo' " "" + mtpt + "  " + "   " +filervol + "'",
    "|", "sudo tee -a", "/etc/"+map, ">", "/dev/null" ], stdout=None, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

mtpt and filervol are both variables defined earlier in the code.

The above code produces this output:

```
sudo: echo junk         junk:/vol/junk: command not found
```

python needs to send:

```
echo "junk              junk:/vol/junk"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Forget about `Popen` for a second and first try to just define each of these strings as a Python variable and print it (or, better, its `repr`) to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you're trying to do complicated things with `ssh`, using a higher-level library like Paramiko or Fabric will probably be a whole lot easier than trying to script the command-line client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
"echo' " ""
```

… but here's how Python will interpret it:

First, `"echo' "` is a 6-character string (the word `echo`, a single `'`, and a space). Then `""` is an empty string. These are concatenated together (forming the same 6-character string, of course).

If you want to put double-quote characters into a double-quoted string, you have to escape them with a backslash, like this:

```
"echo' \" \""
```

However, there's a much, much easier way to deal with this stuff: just using triple-quoting. Most people learn about triple-quoting as a way to handle multi-line strings, and it is great for that—but it's also great for strings that have both kinds of quotes inside:

```
'''echo' " "'''
```

---

Also, instead of opening and closing the quotes over and over again so you can use string concatenation, it's a lot simpler to use a single format string and call `format` on it (or, if you prefer, to use the `%` operator).

---

But meanwhile, if what you're trying to send is this:

```
echo "junk              junk:/vol/junk"
```

I have no idea why you're starting off with `echo'` as the start of the string, but you've clearly gone wrong right off the bat. What you want is something like:

```
'''echo "{0}     {1}"'''.format(mtpt, filervol)
```

I put 5 spaces there because your original code had a 2-space string added to a 3-space string. But your desired output has 14 spaces, so… I'm not sure what you actually want there. If there were tabs involved in your actual code that got lost in copy-pasting to StackOverflow, I'd recommend using `\t` escapes in your literals instead of actual tabs.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. I am running Python 2.6.6, and getting this error: Password: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_amap.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "./update_amap.py", line 62, in main
    '''echo "{}         {}"'''.format(mtpt, filervol),
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: OK, in Python 2.6, you need `{0}` for the first one, `{1}` for the second, etc. They fixed that in 2.7, but if you have to use 2.6, I can edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you, using {0} for the first variable and {1} for the second worked perfectly, as well as your suggestion to use \t for tabs. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `|` or `>` in your command, then you need to also use `shell=True`.

If you use `shell=True`, then the first argument to `Popen` should be a string, not a list:

```
ssh_upd = Popen(
    'ssh {server} sudo -S echo "{mtpt}      {filervol}" | sudo tee -a /etc/{map} > /dev/null'.format(server=server, mtpt=mtpt, filervol=filervol, map=map), stdout=None, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Note that if the command sent to Popen includes user input, then you should not use `shell=True`, since it can be a security risk. (Be sure to read [the Warning in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).)

You can avoid using `shell=True` and the pipe `|`, and the redirect `>` by using multiple Popens -- [connecting one's stdout to the next one's stdin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to put the redirection _inside_ the `ssh` command (that is, tell `ssh` to redirect the `sudo`), not _output_ (that is, tell the shell to redirect `ssh`). If I'm right, then he _doesn't_ want `shell=True` here. (Although I'm still not 100% sure what command he's trying to execute, and there's a good chance he got it wrong in more ways than the one he asked about, so I could very easily be wrong.)

Comment: PS, come on, what's the security risk in letting a user interpose a shell when all you're doing is using ssh to `sudo -S` on a remote server? ;)